# Not allowed to load local resource in Django (Images)

Tags: python-3.x, django, api, google-chrome

I'm trying to load multiple images using Django rest API but getting the error as - Not allowed to load local resource.

the setting of app is -

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I have checked multiple solution on google but is this due to chrome or Django? Can anyone help here please.

NOTE: The call of the API is giving 200 response but only rendering is not happening. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the `STATIC_...` and `MEDIA_...` to `<projectname>/urls.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [...]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns.extend(static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT))
    urlpatterns.extend(static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
```

Or you got some `CORS` issues on your `frontend`.

Comment: the above part is already present in the <project>/urls.py. If it is CORS issue, is there a way to avoid it??

Comment: What framework are you using for the frontend ?